# How do we handle the position change of the item when using SwipeRefreshLayout and RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

Generally, I plan to use SwipeRefreshLayout and RecyclerView to implement Pull-To-Refresh list. After pulling the list to refresh the data, it seems that the original item position has been added one for refreshing widget. Since it is the position of the item that decides what kind of views should be drew or loaded, after refreshing, it was detected that the position of the same item was increased by 1, which directly leads to the IndexOutOfBoundException when I try to access the last item in the original list.

Is there any method that I can handle this position change so that the last item will be available without any exception?

Comment: I'm sure your problem can be solved. RecyclerViews aren't like rocket science. Having said that, *we* can help you much better if you show what you've got so far.

Comment: I agree with you; otherwise, RecyclerView + SwipeRefreshLayout will not be such a famous combo in Android if there is a fatal problem like this. So, what is the decent solution for this?

Comment: Why don't you show us your code so we can show you the next steps to go?

Comment: I have already solved this problem. It turned out to be that the calculation of the items is so complicated that only part of the variable or dataset was updated when pulling to refresh the list. Thank you for your help!